# Does the phrase count on carries connotation?

Tags: meaning, connotations, semantics

I want to ask whether the phrase **count on** contains connotations? I'm not a native speaker and determining connotations makes me confused. In the dictionary, the phrase count on means rely on someone/something but on the other hand it literally means to count on. Can you help me explain this?

Comment: Hi Shua, what do you mean by "contains connotations"? Are you looking for other definitions? Did you check multiple dictionaries?

Comment: "To count on [someone/something]" is a phrasal verb with a different meaning from the verb "to count".  You would know the difference depending on the context.  There may be rare examples when we might use "count on", not as a phrasal verb, but as a ordinary verb followed by the preposition on. I can't actually think of any that would sound natural though. To count [something] on a device", perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, many phrasal verbs have multiple senses, including literal senses.

"Count on" means "rely" in the sentence:

> I'm counting on you to book the trip, that is your main task.

But it is literal in the sentence:

> If you count on from 10 to 15, how many prime numbers will you reach?

But the context makes it clear what sense is intended.